# How to check if the branch I'm in is based on a commit of remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull, git-track

I'm trying to figure out whether I can pull.

If my branch is based on a *remote branch* than he has remote tracking branch, so I can pull.

If my branch is based on a *commit*, it doesn't have a remote tracking branch thus pull would fail.

What I managed to find is that when using the command `git branch -vv`:

1. If there's a remote tracking it will be shown in square brackets. Example: `* origin/before-yo b0b97cf [remotes/origin/before-yo] Move to subfolder`
2. If the branch is based on a commit, there won't be any remote ref indication. Example: `* 2fbe2ab473fe8f7aea2a36642aea1dc7d36add51 2fbe2ab Advance counter`

Is there a better way to understand if there's a remote tracking branch connected to my current working branch?

Also, might `git branch -vv` not work in some cases?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually asking if your branch has a remote tracking branch? `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}` should do that, it will display the remote tracking branch if there is one, or give an error message if not, "fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'XYZ'".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - Thanks. Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Modern ones say `* (HEAD detached at <hash>)` for the detached HEAD case that yours seems to be showing as `* 2fbe2ab...`, your case-2 above.

Comment: @torek - git version `2.7.4`

Comment: Ah, well, 2.7.4 also prints `* (HEAD detached at ...)` so the only way you could get `* 2fbe2ab473fe8f7aea2a36642aea1dc7d36add51` is by creating a branch actually *named* `2fbe2ab473fe8f7aea2a36642aea1dc7d36add51`, e.g., `git checkout -b 2fbe2ab473fe8f7aea2a36642aea1dc7d36add51`. While Git allows this, it's not a good idea, as it now becomes ambiguous whether that name means the hash ID, or the branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script which shows what you really want: after `git fetch`, it shows the difference between local and remote branches, thus you will know what you have to do (`pull`, `push`, `rebase`, etc.). Put the directory of it to somewhere on your [PATH](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) and you can use it as `git fetch-log`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# git-fetch-log: Ultimate git fetch-log
#
# It shows the diferences of `local...remote` if both side exists and there
# are differences. Useful to find out what you have to do: `merge`, `rebase`,
# `push`, etc. The arguments passed to log.
#
# Place it somewhere on Your `$PATH` and execute by the `git fetch-log`
# command.
#
#                               EXAMPLE OUTPUT
# ============================================================================
#
# ==== branch [behind 1]
#
# > commit 652b883 (origin/branch)
# | Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
# | Date:   2016-03-10 09:11:11 +0100
# |
# |     Commit on remote
# |
# o commit 2304667 (branch)
#   Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
#   Date:   2015-08-28 13:21:13 +0200
#
#       Commit on local
#
# ==== master [ahead 1]
#
# < commit 280ccf8 (master)
# | Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
# | Date:   2016-03-25 21:42:55 +0100
# |
# |     Commit on local
# |
# o commit 2369465 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
#   Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
#   Date:   2016-03-10 09:02:52 +0100
#
#       Commit on remote
#
# ==== test [ahead 1, behind 1]
#
# < commit 83a3161 (test)
# | Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
# | Date:   2016-03-25 22:50:00 +0100
# |
# |     Diverged from remote
# |
# | > commit 4aafec7 (origin/test)
# |/  Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
# |   Date:   2016-03-14 10:34:28 +0100
# |
# |       Pushed remote
# |
# o commit 0fccef3
#   Author: BimbaLaszlo <bimbalaszlo@gmail.com>
#   Date:   2015-09-03 10:33:39 +0200
#
#       Last common commit

  fmt='ref=%(refname:short); up=%(upstream:short); t=%(upstream:track); ts=%(upstream:trackshort);'
  git for-each-ref --shell --format="$fmt" refs/heads | \
  while read entry; do
    eval "$entry"
    if test "z$ts" != 'z' && test "z$ts" != 'z='; then
      echo -e "\n==== $ref $t\n"
      git --no-pager log --graph --left-right --decorate --abbrev-commit --date-order --boundary $@ $ref...$up
    fi
  done
```

https://gitlab.com/bimlas/home/blob/3fb207cdfe57593a78abe30150a3bc40b242e26a/linux/home/.gitconfig_files/custom_commands/git-fetch-log